# Read Socket InputStream

Tags: sockets, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I'm trying to allow my computer to send video files to my app (Windows Phone 8). I use a socket to show a html file on my computer where I can select a file and upload it

if file is large size receive memory exception.
how to solve?

this is my code

```
private async void HandleRequest(StreamSocket socket)
{
    //Initialize IO classes
    DataReader reader = new DataReader(socket.InputStream);
    reader.InputStreamOptions = InputStreamOptions.Partial;

    // read request
    var stringHeader = await reader.LoadAsync(4);

    if (stringHeader == 0)
    {
       // disconnected
       return;
    }

    // get length
    int length = reader.ReadInt32();

    // initiate data
    byte[] data = new byte[length];

    // load and read data
    uint bytes = await reader.LoadAsync((uint)length);
    reader.ReadBytes(data);
}
```

Comment: If this does not work, please detail how.

Comment: receive memory leak with large files